# gitのコンテンツをビルド後、成果物を別のgitリポジトリへpushするプラグインはありますか？

Tags: jenkins

閲覧頂きありがとうございます。

jenkinsのプラグインの中にclone元とpush先、それぞれでリポジトリURLを設定できるプラグインはありますでしょうか。

いままではシェルを作って、それを利用していたのですが、プラグインがあるならばそちらに切り替えたいです。